# Error using GeckoFx 22 in C#.Net

Tags: c#, geckofx

I am creating an application C#.Net framework 4.0 that uses the Component GeckoFX 22 and I'm not getting to do work .. I make all references, all right..I'm running on x86, all according to what they asked for in the project ..

My project: https:// mega.co.nz/#!KMZgGQ7S!RDs0-AHjHXiSiyvfVAyZQk0Si9Aq2InA-dbMV2BpzoA
*remove the space after http://

geckofx22 = https:// bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-22.0

*remove the space after http://

xulrunner = http:// ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/22.0/runtimes/xulrunner-22.0.en-US.win32.zip
*remove the space after http://

see code bellow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Gecko;


namespace Browser_GeckoFx22
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Xpcom.Initialize(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\xulrunner");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

image project: http:// postimg.org/image/cekuka9nn/
*remove the space after http://

see the error as I run: http:// postimg.org/image/usvdo9lyb/
*remove the space after http://

thx

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, but maybe your profile directory really is messed up? Here's a page of things to check:http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/couldnt-initialize-applications-security-component. You can also try having your app create its own profile, using Xpcom.ProfileDirectory= @"c:\somepath".

Comment: you tested and it worked or just read the code?

Comment: I added the location and it worked .. thanks ..
        Xpcom.ProfileDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\DefaultProfile";